# Relation Big-O and limit of a function?

Tags: limits, asymptotics

It is not clear to me what it the relationship (if any) between Big-O and limit of a function. Suppose that a function $f(x)=O(g(x))$: does this imply that $f(x)$ converges to a limit as $x\rightarrow \infty$? And viceversa, suppose that $f(x)$ converges to a limit as $x\rightarrow \infty$: does this imply that there exists a function $g(x)$ s.t. $f(x)=O(g(x))$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we say a function $f$ is $O(g)$ we are making a statement about its asymptotic behavior. This means that there exists some threshold $M\gt 0$ and some constant $N$ such that $x\gt M\implies |f(x)|\le N|g(x)|$.

Let's compare this to the definition of a limit.

$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = L$ if for all $\epsilon\gt 0$ there exists $M\gt 0$ such that $x\gt M\implies |f(x)-L|\lt\epsilon$.

The two different definitions are very similar but not the same. With big $O$ notation we are simply saying that, for large $x$, the magnitude of $f$ is no larger than the magnitude of $g$. The limit is saying that $f$ is getting arbitrarily close to a constant.

To see if you understand this I leave you with two exercises.

1. If $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = L$, prove that $f$ is $O(1)$
2. Prove that $f$ is $O(f)$

Answer (score 1):

As a mathematics major, this question will have a more mathematical explanation. As a first resource, you should look at the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). It is a great resource.

After this, I would like to say that, at least from a math perspective, $f(x) \neq O(g(x))$, generally. There is a great discussion in the wiki article on this.

What relates to limits in the expression "$f(x) = O(g(x))$"? Well, motivation for this starts when we would like to talk about the behavior of a function, $f$, as values of $x$ get arbitrarily large. Thus, it is often meant by $f(x) = O(g(x))$, that there exists an $M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $$f(x) \leq M \cdot g(x)$$ for all $x \geq x_0$ for some $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$. In particular, this is true when $x \rightarrow \infty$; the most straightforward examples are when $g$, $f$ are polynomials.

As a more accurate description of $f(x) = O(g(x))$, we should say $f(x) \in O(g(x))$, where $O(g(x))$ is a set. In particular, it is the set which describes a family of functions which have a "leading" term, $g(x)$: "thinking of $O(g(x))$ as the class of all functions $h(x)$ such that $|h(x)| ≤ C|g(x)|$ for some constant $C$". This makes much more sense and answers your last question.

In the context of computer science, big-O notation is probably used too liberally.

Answer (score 1):

Big-O notation isn't really about limits as $x\to\infty$. It's about rate of growth, *how quickly* functions diverge (get big and stay big). In what follows, assume we're talking about functions that have nonnegative values, defined either on the nonnegative reals or integers.

$O$ is uninteresting for a function that has a limit as $x\to\infty$:

> If $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = L$ some real number $L$, then $f = O(1)$.

Thus if $f$ is such a function, it's one of the slowest growing, and least interesting, functions, asymptotically speaking. To see this, note that there's $x_0$ such that for all $x\ge x_0$, $f(x) < L + 1 = k\cdot 1$ where $k=L+1$.

So in a sense, $O$ notation is only interesting for functions that *don't* have limits as their arguments "approach infinity".

$O$ notation comes into its own as a means of comparing rates of growth, e.g. worst-case analyses for the running time of algorithms. To say that $f = O(g)$ means that *eventually* (for all $x\ge$ some $x_0$), $f$ is bounded above by a constant times $g$. $g$ is, to within a constant multiple, *eventually* an upper bound of $f$.

A few standard examples:

- if $f$ is $O(\log_2 n)$ (meaning, the function $n\mapsto \log_2 n$) then $f$ grows fairly slowly;
- if $f$ is $O(n^2)$, it's bounded above by a quadratic polynomial;
- if $f$ is $O(2^n)$ then its bounded above by an exponential function, which gets big fast.

Whereas $\log_2 n$ is $O(n^2)$ (and $\log_2$ is also $O(2^n)$), the reverse is not true: $n^2$ outstrips $\log_2 n$, you can't bound it above by any constant times any log function. Similarly, $2^n$ grows faster than any polynomial, and faster than $\log_2$.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers provide context, I'll just provide the condensed answers to your questions:

**1. No**, $f(x)\in\mathcal{O}(g(x))$ doesn't need to converge, take for example $g=f$: For *every* $f$ we have that $f(x)\in\mathcal{O}(f(x))$ (trivially), but if you choose a divergent $f$, well, it doesn't converge.

**2. Yes**, convergence implies $f(x)\in\mathcal{O}(g(x))$ since then $f$ is bounded for large $x$, i.e. $|f(x)|\leq M\cdot 1$ for all large enough $x$, so we can even choose $g(x)=1$ for all $x$ and deduce $f(x)\in\mathcal{O}(1)$.